# Canny edge detector is detecting the borders of the images

Tags: matlab, canny-operator

```
clear_all();

image_name = 'canny_test.png';

% no of  pixels discarded on border areas
discard_pixels = 10;

% read image and convert to grayscale
input_image = gray_imread(image_name);

% discard border area
input_image = discard_image_area(input_image, discard_pixels);

% create a binary image
binary_image = edge(input_image,'canny');    
imshow(binary_image);
```

**Input**

[image]

**Expected Outcome**

[image]

**Actual Outcome**

[image]

Here, we see that the borderlines of the image are being detected by the Canny Edge Detector which is not my expected outcome.

**How can I achieve this?**

---

*Source Code*

```
function [output_image] = discard_image_area( input_image, pixel_count)
    output_image = input_image;

    [height, width] = size(input_image);

    % discard top
    output_image(1:pixel_count, :) = 0;
    % discard bottom
    h = height - pixel_count;
    output_image(h:height, :) = 0;    
    % discard left
    output_image(:,1:pixel_count) = 0;
    % discard right
    output_image(:,(width-pixel_count):width) = 0;
end

function img = gray_imread( image_name )
    I = imread(image_name);

    if(is_rgb(I))
        img = rgb2gray(I);
    elseif (is_gray(I))
        img = I;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `discard_image_area` after applying the `edge` function. Otherwise the discarded area makes its boundary apparently. i.e. do this:

```
image_name = 'canny_test.png';
discard_pixels = 10;
input_image =  rgb2gray(imread(image_name));  % there is no such this as gray_imread

% create a binary image
binary_image = edge(input_image,'canny');    

% discard border area
binary_image = discard_image_area(binary_image , discard_pixels);

imshow(binary_image);
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: `% there is no such this as gray_imread` -- this is my custom function.

Comment: Did you define it anywhere in your question? No. Then there is no such thing

Comment: Is there any built-in Matlab function available which works in the same way as my `discard_image_area`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of! I don't think there's anything wrong with `discard_image_area`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, your function `discard_image_area` changes the image value to 0 near the borders of the image.

Hence it creates Step between the image value and 0.
This is exactly what the Canny Edge Detector looks for.

You can easily see it if you display the image after applying the function.

Just don't use that function.

Comment: `Just don't use that function.` --- in that case, the border lines are seen on the edges of the image.

Comment: @anonymous, So crop it, don't make the values into 0.